# DRF SearchFilter Datetimefield Unsupported lookup 'gte'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a field ***timestamp*** which is a DateTime field when I'm filtering by this field in the shell it works fine with '__gte' or '__lte'

```
$ python manage.py shell     
>>> from inventory.models import Order
>>> Order.objects.filter(timestamp__date__gte=('2022-06-06'))
>>> <QuerySet [<Order: ID: 22>, <Order_id: 27>, ....]
```

but when I use SearchFilter it raises an error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'gte' for DateField or join on the field not permitted, perhaps you meant gte or gt or lte?`

#### models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

#### views.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework import filters

class Invoices(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = InvoicesSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, CustomModelPermissions]
    queryset = serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['timestamp__date__gte']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter doesn't work because, [as per docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter),

> The search_fields attribute should be a list of names of text type fields on the model, such as CharField or TextField

If you want GTE lookup then you will need to add a [FilterSet](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html), e.g. like in [How to create datetime filter using Django Rest Framework Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675479/how-to-create-datetime-filter-using-django-rest-framework-filters).

Comment: sad there is nothing that built-in

Answer (score 0):

Just try to apply filter without __date

```
Order.objects.filter(timestamp__gte= datetime.date(2022,6,6))
```

Or

```
Order.objects.filter(timestamp__gte='2022-06-06')
```

Because your field **timestamp** is already date field